# Should aria-current="page" be used for a client-side table pagination component?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

It is my understanding that aria-current="page" should be used for a set of links when the link is for the current page. How does this relate to a table pagination component, where clicking the link does not navigate to a new page, but instead just changes the rows that are visible in the table?

Is this still appropriate for a page with multiple data tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aria-current` should be used if you have a set of things and one of them can be selected and has a different visual appearance based on it being selected.  Whether that's a list of links or table pagination doesn't matter.

There are [various values](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-current) that can be used for `aria-current`.  It used to only allow "true" and "false" and that would cause the screen reader to announce "current" after it announces the link name.

If you use `page` or `step` or one of the other values, most screen readers will say "current page" or "current step" after it announces the link name.

For example, if you have a table pagination widget like this:

<kbd>[image: table pagination widget]</kbd>

then when I navigate through the numbers, I should hear:

- *"page 1, link"*
- *"page 2, link"*
- *"page 3, link, current page"*
- *"page 4, link"*

and that can be accomplished with

```
<a aria-label="page 3" aria-current="page">3</a>
```

I could use `aria-current="true"` and that would change the announcement to:

- *"page 3, link, current"*

**Note:** I also specified an `aria-label` for the link because otherwise I would just hear "3, link".  Hearing that might not be too bad if the container for all the links (preferably a `<nav>` element) has an `aria-label` that says the widget is for paging through the table.

Comment: Btw also Bootstrap recommends `aria-current="page"`